# Determine cached instances in a Ribbon (+ Feign) client

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix, netflix-eureka, netflix-feign

We're building a microservice architecture on Spring Cloud + NetflixOSS and so far **IT'S AMAZING**. However we have noticed that when we first spin up Eureka + 2 separate microservices, Service1 cannot connect to Service2 for a good ~30 seconds, even though both register with Eureka very quickly and appear up individually. This happens locally or deployed (on AWS via Tutum)

The error we get is:

> Load balancer does not have available server for client: Service1

Pretty much all of our timeouts and settings are just specified as the default, so we feel like there's something wrong. What we're worried about is rolling an update to a Service1 and having it register to Eureka & then having 30 seconds of downtime (or possibly downtime on Service2 that depends on Service1)

Has anyone seen this behavior before? Is there a way to inspect / debug / log the client-side load balancing candidate? We've fished through a lot of the Netflix code (both with / without the debugger) but we're not seeing a lot of logging and introspection points that will be useful (especially since the Observables tend to timeout during deep debugging sessions)

Advice? Suggestions? Pagan gods whom desire sacrifices?

Thanks

Comment: That is the normal default behavior that Netflix wants. There are settings in eureka and ribbon that can be tweaked. It might be later tonight or tomorrow that I get specific properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ribbon.ServerListRefreshInterval=2000` will set the client side to refresh every 2 seconds.

Comment: in the root of `bootstrap.yml` or `application.yml`? I've tried that and still don't get a refresh on a consumers local cache, even though the EurekaServer lists it

Comment: I set the value and see `DynamicServerListLoadBalancer.updateListOfServers` happen every two seconds. Something else must be going on. You said you confirmed with debug, where were you debugging?

Comment: Ahhh got it, thanks. I was lost in the packages and inspecting in the wrong spot. I also had left a IClientConfig on the feign instance that caused a conflict after putting the setting at the root of `app.yml`. I see it polling now ever 2 seconds, but it still seems to take about 6-8 seconds *after* Eureka Server shows it as ready. Is that normal? Or is there another knob I can twist?